# Pythonでの多次元配列の選び方

Tags: python, python3, array, numpy

Python3.6を使用してます。
np.arrayで下の配列と範囲を与えられたとき
arr[a][b][c][d]  
a --1 ～ 72
b -- 0 ～ 11
c -- 0 ～ 9
d --  0 ～ 4500
このような形でarr1に代入したいのですが

arr1 = arr[全て(1-72)][12個からから1つ][全て(0 - 9][全て(0 - 4500]

どうやればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: arr[:,1,:,:]とかじゃダメですか？

Answer (score 2):

NumPy では Python の添え字記法を拡張して使えるようにしており、ある軸の要素を全部取りたいときは `:` を指定すれば取ることができます。

実行例:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.zeros((72, 12, 10, 4501))
>>> arr.shape
(72, 12, 10, 4501)
>>> arr1 = arr[:, 5, :, :]  # 試しに 5 番目の行を取ってきてみます
>>> arr1.shape
(72, 10, 4501)
```

より詳しい使い方については、NumPy ドキュメントの [Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) に書かれています。